# Regex for allowing alphanumeric and space in Field Validation Module of Drupal

Tags: php, regex, drupal, drupal-7

I have `Drupal 7` site. I am using contributed "Field Validation" module for validation.

I need to validate textbox. This textbox should allow only characters, numerics & space.

I tried with the following regex but not allowing spaces.

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- `^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$`
- `/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i`

Please note here I am talking about **regex in FieldValidation module of drupal**.

Comment: Try `^[A-Za-z0-9_\s-]*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew.. checked still not allowing space

Comment: Well, make sure you use `/.../` regex delimiters, and try `/^[a-zA-Z-_0-9 ]*$/`

Answer (score 1):

This should work  `^[\w\s]+$`

```
^  - assert position at start of the string
\w - Matches alphanumeric (same as [a-zA-Z0-9_])
\d - Matches digits (same as [0-9])
+  - Match the previous element one or more times (as many as possible)
$  - assert position at end of the string
```

This is what is allowed to write in this text box

```
ABCdef 123_
```

P.S. if this `^[\w\s]+$` isn't work try `/^[\w\s]+$/`